# How can I save data from POST method to the database from a forms.Model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Since few hours ago I am facing a basic problem so I have decided to ask a question after tried to do many many example but I still can't save the data from my forms using POST method.

Into my template views, when I post a data and from my web page nothing go to the database and even when I do print(request.POST) I got nothing, its seem like nothing work.

I am using Django 2.2 the latest version of Django.

This my models:

```
class AddressDelivery(models.Model):

    billing_profile = models.ForeignKey(BillingProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name      = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    last_name       = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    address_type    = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=ADDRESS_TYPES)
    address_line_1  = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    address_line_2  = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    city            = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    phone           = PhoneNumberField(unique=True)
    country         = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=COUNTRIES, default=current_country)
    state_or_department  = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    postal_code     = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    def __str__(self):
        return str('{}'.format(self.billing_profile))
```

This is my forms:

```
class AddressForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = AddressDelivery
        fields = [
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'phone',
            #'billing_profile',
            #'address_type',
            'address_line_1',
            'address_line_2',
            'city',
            'postal_code',
            'state_or_department',
            'country',
        ]
        widgets = {
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'First Name'}),
            'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Last Name'}),
            'postal_code': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'postal code'}),
            'state_or_department': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'state or department'}),
            'city': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'city'}),
            'address_type': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'address_line_1': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'address line 1'}),
            'address_line_2': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'address line 2'}),
            'country': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'address_type': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'phone': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Phone number with country code'}),

        }
```

And here is my views to handler the forms:

```
def checkout_address_create_view(request):
    form = AddressForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        "form": form
    }
    next_ = request.GET.get('next')
    next_post = request.POST.get('next')
    redirect_path = next_ or next_post or None
    if form.is_valid():
        print(request.POST)
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        billing_profile, billing_profile_created = BillingProfile.objects.new_or_get(request)
        if billing_profile is not None:
            address_type = request.POST.get('address_type', 'shipping')
            instance.billing_profile = billing_profile
            instance.address_type = request.POST.get('address_type', 'shipping') 
            instance.save()

        else:
            print("Error here")
            return redirect("checkout")

        if is_safe_url(redirect_path, request.get_host()):
            return redirect(redirect_path)
        else:
            return redirect("checkout")
    return redirect("checkout")
```

And this is my template form:

```
 <form method="POST" action="{% if action_url %}{{ action_url }}{% else %}{% url 'login' %}{% endif %}"> {% csrf_token %}
{% if next_url %}
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next_url }}" />
{% endif %}

{% if address_type %}
<input type="hidden" name="address_type" value="{{ address_type }}" />
{% endif %}
{{ form.as_p }}
```

Submit

This register views used the same method and its working fine, correctly:

```
def register(request):
  # get_variable_country()
  # print(get_variable_country())
  get_variable_model()
  print(get_variable_model())

if request.user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect('index')
elif request.user.is_authenticated and (request.user.is_admin == True):
    return redirect('index')
else:

    form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        'form': form
        }
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save() 
        return redirect('thanks')
    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', context)
```

Please help thank you.

Comment: The latest version of Django is Django 2.2

Comment: `form.is_valid()` is probably `False`, print it before entering the condition.

Comment: you might want to print `request.method` and `request.POST` as the first line in your view... (also, I would recommend learning to use a debugger...)

Comment: Oh @LouisSaglio you right and I upgraded it to the latest one 2.2

Comment: are you sure you're posting data from your browser? did you check in your browser developer tools what the request is (method = POST and the data being posted)?

Comment: @dirkgroten I just did request.method == 'POST' but he doesn't print anything

Comment: I meant to check in your browser (use the debugger tools to look at the HTTP request sent by your browser), not printing something in python. Also, as mentioned by @thebjorn, use a debugger so you can set a breakpoint at the top of your view and inspect the variables, like `request`, `request.method` and `request.POST` and then step through line by line so see what's happening.

Comment: @dirkgroten I am working with three different browser, chrome, opera and firefox the all don't work so that is why I think the problem came from my code maybe.

Comment: They are all running the same HTML/javascript (which is part of your code). That's where I think your error is.

Comment: I just updated my question because I use the same method to register and it work fine, no problem.

Comment: @dirkgroten I am sure because I used the same method to register and to login without any problem

Comment: I'm just telling you how to debug this kind of issue: 1. look in the browser at the request, to be sure it's actually sending a post request (does your <form> tag have method='post' set?) and to be sure the data is correct (is the template correct?). 2. set a breakpoint in your view and inspect the variables. 3. step through your code in the debugger line by line to see the code execution path. Your code looks ok, so maybe the problem is in the view creating the template with the empty form or in the template. You would be able to tell if you follow the debug steps.

Comment: @dirkgroten I just updated again my question by putting also my template form and everything ok. I don't why he doesn't save it.

Comment: have you tried the debug steps i mention? that's the only way to find out the problem. Not by looking at code.

Comment: I did but nothing seem to work !

Comment: Please update your question with the raw request headers and request params (you just said you did it, you need to tell us what the result was -- we can't read your mind). Also, as I said 3 hours ago... print `request.method` and `request.POST` as the first line in your view... and update you question with what is printed. Just dumping a bunch of code isn't going to help neither us nor you find what the problem is (removing code until the problem goes away is a much better approach).

Comment: ps: looking at your profile.. it doesn't seem like you have upvoted or accepted _any_ answers to your questions.. (why?)  If you need as much help as this, that is the least you could do.. just saying.

Comment: @thebjorn I couldn't understand what you meant. the is that I done the same method for register and it work perfectly without a problem. I don't know why he refuse with this modelform.

Comment: This isn't a magic spell where you can just swish your wand and make things happen, you actually have to do the work required. @dirkgroten has very patiently told you what you need to do to see what is happening - which is fundamental to figuring out what is wrong. Ignoring him and saying "but it works for this other code" is disrespectful of the time he has put into helping you. Combine that with the fact that you have "0 votes cast" and have only accepted 1 answer on any of your questions and you make it seem like helping you will just be feeding a giant black hole. Please prove me wrong.

Comment: @thebjorn there's no point to prove you anything about what your gars were saying and I thank you all for trying to help me. I am just try to to make understand also there's no reason at all why he work for the same method. after I reviewing my code. I can see that, even when I clicked on the link to submit, but he never took me to the link I want to. so this is my big mistake now. not my code because my code is correct after reviewing my whole code. so the problem came from my html file but I don't where !.

Comment: @thebjorn about my profile I don't know what you meant, I have checked my profile and I didn't see what you are asking me to change. Please could you show me how to do it ? . thank you very much.

Comment: Hello to everyone, as I told you gars that isn't what you were thinking for. I just resolved the problem right now and I am so happy. Thank you for all.